# Adding paging to get_posts()

Tags: pagination, get-posts

I'm trying to add paging to the query below. However, I can't seem to get the paging to work. It shows previous/next links, however, they always show the same 2 posts. There are 8 posts in this query.

```
//$paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
wp_reset_query();

global $post;

$args = array('posts_per_page' => 2,'paged'=>1);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: You are overwriting any pagination variables with 'paged' => 1, it's not a boolean flag but the current page indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make `paged` equal to `get_query_var( 'paged' )` that should do the trick. You may need to do something like `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;` and then set `paged` to `$paged`.